# Integrating three APIs in HTML website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to integrate these three APIs in my HTML website.

Every time subsequent  cancels out the previous one and only the last one runs.

HTML

```
  <div class="container1">
   <div id="container-table"></div>
   <div id="container-tablec"></div>
   <div id="container-tableq"></div>
   <div id="container-table"></div>
   <div id="container-table"></div>
  </div>
```

JavaScript

```
<script>
  $('document').ready(function(){
      refreshData();
  })

  function refreshData() {
      $('#container-table').load("data.php", function(){
          setTimeout(refreshData, 10000);
      });
  }
</script>

<script>
  $('document').ready(function(){
      refreshData();
  })

  function refreshData() {
      $('#container-tablec').load("datacex.php", function(){
          setTimeout(refreshData, 10000);
      });

  }
</script>


<script>
  $('document').ready(function(){
      refreshData();
  })

  function refreshData() {
      $('#container-tableq').load("dataquad.php", function(){
          setTimeout(refreshData, 10000);
      });
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Don't use `div` elements with the same `id`. You probably will want to use classes.

Comment: Well what do you expect to happen when you have multiple things with the same function name? They overwrite each other...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @MátéSolymosi and @JiFus said, you can't reuse element IDs or function names.  That's why you're having issues.

Below is your same code, but with the `div` IDs changed to classes, and the function names differentiated based on where they are called from.

**Summary of changes:**

- Changed `div` IDs to classes
- Changed function names to be unique
- Changed `.load()` function to use class name instead of ID

You could of course change the function names to whatever you like, and you could use unique IDs instead of classes for the `div`s (like `container-table1`, `container-table2`, etc.)

```html
<div class="container1">
   <div class="container-table"></div>
   <div class="container-tablec"></div>
   <div class="container-tableq"></div>
   <div class="container-table"></div>
   <div class="container-table"></div>
</div>

<script>
  $('document').ready(function(){
      refreshData();
  })

  function refreshData() {
      $('.container-table').load("data.php", function(){
          setTimeout(refreshData, 10000);
      });
  }
</script>

<script>
  $('document').ready(function(){
      refreshDataC();
  })

  function refreshDataC() {
      $('.container-tablec').load("datacex.php", function(){
          setTimeout(refreshDataC, 10000);
      });

  }
</script>

<script>
  $('document').ready(function(){
      refreshDataQ();
  })

  function refreshDataQ() {
      $('.container-tableq').load("dataquad.php", function(){
          setTimeout(refreshDataQ, 10000);
      });
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You **cannot have multiple functions with the same name**, even if they are in different `<script>` tags. When you define the second `refreshData`, it will overwrite the first one.

Set different names for all 3 functions.

---

You could also consolidate the three `<script>` blocks into one:

```html
<script>
  $('document').ready(function(){
      refreshData();
  });

  function refreshData() {
      $('#container-table').load("data.php", function() {
          setTimeout(refreshData, 10000);
      });
      
      $('#container-tablec').load("datacex.php", function() {
          setTimeout(refreshData, 10000);
      });
      
      $('#container-tableq').load("dataquad.php", function() {
          setTimeout(refreshData, 10000);
      });
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not use the same function again and again because when you write it the second time it will over right the first one. So just change your function name.
I think then it will work.